# how to use listview with riverpod in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, riverpod

I'am developing an app with flutter and flutter_riverpod. I want to use listview with riverpod. But I don't know how to use. I have an onSubmitted method of textfield. This method to work some dart code for texffield text. My purpose is save the words to listview. I am using flutter_riverpod for that purpuse but I don't know how to use lists for stateprovider or any other provider.

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(child: ana1()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final List<String> myList= [];
final StateProvider<int> _lengthProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

class ana1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
                width: 500,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Content Text',
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (inText) {
                    print(inText);

                    String gir = inText;
                            String myText = "$gir a";
                            var a = 0;

                            List<String> myList = [];

                            for (a = 0; a < myText.length; a++) {
                              if (myText.substring(a, a + 1) == " ") {
                                myList.add(myText.substring(0, a));
                                myText = myText.substring(a + 1, myText.length);
                                a = 0;
                              }
                            }
                            
                            var b = 0;
                            String errorText = "?.; :-";

                            for (b = 0; b < myList.length; b++) {
                              String checkF = myList[b].substring(0, 1);
                              if (errorText.contains(checkF)) {
                                myList[b] =
                                    myList[b].substring(1, myList[b].length);
                              }

                              String checkL = myList[b].substring(
                                  myList[b].length - 1, myList[b].length);
                              if (errorText.contains(checkL)) {
                                myList[b] = myList[b]
                                    .substring(0, myList[b].length - 1);
                              }
                            }



 myList.add("$inText-${myList.length + 1}");
      ref.read(_lengthProvider.state).state = myList.length;




                  },
                )),
            Container(
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              width: 500,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ref.watch(_lengthProvider.state).state,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(myList[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am simplifying the snippet to work out with state provider only

```dart
final StateProvider<List<String>> itemsProvider = StateProvider((ref) => []);

class ana1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Content Text',
              ),
                           onSubmitted: (inText) {
                final sliptIntoWords = inText.split(
                    ","); // Im separating words on , perform your logic here
                final oldItems = ref.read(itemsProvider);
                ref.read(itemsProvider.state).update(
                      (state) => [
                        ...oldItems,
                        ...sliptIntoWords,
                      ],
                    );
              },
            )),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: ref.watch(itemsProvider).length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text(ref.watch(itemsProvider)[index]);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

It will better using cosumer on `ListView` I think

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But It is not my what ı want completely, but so nearly. I want to enter text in texfield and save the words as a list. I can save the words as dart list but I cant save to listview. If you look my onsubmitted method you can see how ı do it. Please help me about this issue. Because it's important for me. Thank you for your answers. Last of all sorry for my bad English

Comment: For example ı want to enter 'Table, pencil, door, laptop'. and ı want to save as a list these 4 words.

Comment: I think I’ve got it. Do you like to extend the list or just entered sentence to words list? is it ok if i just split the words and feed on list, hope you can handle the separation

Comment: Let's say that we have an article or only a sentence. We should find the words from the article or sentence. And we should show the words on a listview. For example sentence: 'Yeasin is the most helpful person'. This is our sentence or small article. We should show the words on the listview like Yeasin\n is\n the\n most\n helpful\person. The words are the items on listview. We have 6 words so we have 6 items in listview. This is the problem. can ı explain.

Comment: for space use `inText.split(" ")`, if you don't like to update the list remove `...oldItems`

Comment: hmm I understand thank you for you answer. I found the correct answer.